Is there anyway to open the sharepoint in File explorer?
I am trying to open my sharepoint documents in my file explorer, i see some suggestion they ask us to enable Open in explorer by using IE browser 32 bit in Edge browser, i tried but the sharepoint throws the error as It's time to upgrade your browser
SharePoint and OneDrive use new browser technology and work best in the latest browsers. Any idea to fix this

Which version of SharePoint are you using exactly?
